# How to write the list into corresponding columns

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlwt

Thanks in advance! I have 3 lists with text, each of them comes with 8 datapoints.

I want the output into the A,C,D columns of excel spreadsheet.

I'm using the `pyExcelerator`, the biggest problem is when I rerun the program, it replaces the original program. I just want the results adding to the existing excel spreadsheet. Like `a` option in `file.write`.

```
    indexlist = list();
    indexlist2 = list();
    indexlist3 = list();
    #keep adding new element at same speed
    indexlist.append(a);
    indexlist2.append(b);
    indexlist3.append(c);


#create the new excel spreadsheet   
w = Workbook()  
ws = w.add_sheet('sheet') 

for i in range(len(indexlist)):
    ws.write(i+1,3,str(indexlist[i]))   
for j in range(len(indexlist2)):
    ws.write(j+1,2,str(indexlist2[j]))  
for k in range(len(indexlist3)):
    ws.write(k+1,0,str(indexlist3[k]))
```

Comment: I am not familiar with pyExcelator, but your rows are 1-indexed and columns are 0-indexed - is this correct? Can you post more of your code - what is `ws` for instance?

Comment: You have 3 lists of 8 integers, not text. What are `indexlist`, `indexlist2`, etc? Why is the last `for` loop calling `ws.write(k+1,0,str(indexlist3[k]))` instead of `ws.write(k+1,1,str(indexlist3[k]))`?

Comment: see updates, the list doesn't matter, I'm putting text into the list use append function.

Answer (score 0):

It rewrites the values in the rows since i, j and k are the row numbers you write to and they start at 0 each time you run the program. What you need to do is open the file for reading firs, see if the sheet exists, if not continue to write into it for the first time, if the sheet exists see what the last row number is (there is a nrows function available in xlrd), close the file and reopen it for writing. Then add that value to i+1, j+1 and k+1 in your ws.write statements.